# Fail to install grub in a partition

Tags: grub2, system-installation, uefi

I try to install ubuntu as following:
/dev/sda1 primary , ext4 mounted as: /      , for ubuntu
/dev/sda2 primary , fat32 or ext4(?),  mounted as: /boot  , for grub
/dev/sda3 primary , other use

But it keeps failing whenever it gets to grub install, there is a window showing that "failed to install grub on / target...".

I am not sure what's wrong in what I am doing.

Is it a BIOS/UEFI issue ? Should I mount into other mount point, or use other format ?

I try to install ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: if you want to create separate boot partition.. /boot should be ext4. if its UEFI booting and single OS.. first you need EFI System Partition.

Comment: What does it mean " first you need EFI System Partition" ? What's the error in the layout above ?

Comment: are you bootibg in BIOS mode or UEFI mode? and dual boot or Single OS? this simplifies your Question to Answer

Comment: If UEFI: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu  And new version uses swap file, so swap partition not required.

Comment: Just a FYI:  The program grub is installed mostly in your /boot/ partition or directory (stages 1.5-2), however it does have Stage 1 (MBR) which is installed on a drive (not partition) as it must be the first 512 bytes of the disk as that is what BIOS/hardware boots (if not using UEFI).  The /boot/ location will be worked out by your installer, when asked for a location it's usually the drive (MBR) you are being asked for which is a drive, not a partition (as defined by hardware boot requirements for x86/x86_64).